# GIT fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree in Travis

Tags: git, bash, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have the following configuration:

```
git version 1.8.5.6
GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

I called `zgit_info_update` and also tried to make commit. But I am still encountering with issue when run `git diff --name-only dev` from Bash in Travis (*[Git diff command returns error #6069](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6069)*).

How can I get this working?

Here the output:

```
git version 1.8.5.6
GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later       <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
* (detached from FETCH_HEAD)
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
[detached HEAD 72afa70] Add package.json
 1 file changed, 37 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 package.json
fatal: ambiguous argument 'dev': unknown revision or path not in the   working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: Stab in the dark: try `git pull` ing first?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by using the commands below:

```
if [ "$TRAVIS" == "true" ]; then
  # Resolving `detached HEAD` by attaching HEAD to the `TRAVIS_FROM_BRANCH` branch
  TRAVIS_FROM_BRANCH="travis_from_branch"
  git branch $TRAVIS_FROM_BRANCH
  git checkout $TRAVIS_FROM_BRANCH

  # Fetching `TRAVIS_BRANCH` branch
  git fetch origin $TRAVIS_BRANCH
  git checkout -qf FETCH_HEAD
  git branch $TRAVIS_BRANCH
  git checkout $TRAVIS_BRANCH

  # Switch to `TRAVIS_FROM_BRANCH`
  git checkout $TRAVIS_FROM_BRANCH
fi
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What is it supposed to do and achieve? Why are 7 Git invocations necessary? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37321632/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler fix is

```
git remote set-branches --add origin $BRANCH_TO_DIFF_AGAINST
git fetch
git diff origin/$BRANCH_TO_DIFF_AGAINST
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Why does it fix the problem? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67920125/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: This is very similar to [defrex's comment on the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6069#issuecomment-266546552).